# Android Studio: Save format file to the repo

Tags: android, android-studio

We are having an issue on a team involving several team members using Android Studio. Basically, I am not sure why, but the formatting is different across different Android Studio versions. This is of course annoying for version control, so I would like to know what is idiomatic way of synchronizing the formatting between several users. My preference would be to commit a format file to the repo to ensure that everybody is using exactly the same formatting.

Our team has a lot of experience working with C++ projects, where we would typically just push a `clang-format` file to the repo so that we are all using the same formatting. However, Android Studio doesn't seem to support `clang-format`.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is just add contents of the `.idea\codeStyles\` like `Project.xml` and `codeStyleConfig.xml` to version control. Also exclude it from `.gitignore` with:

```
#IntelliJ
  ...
  .idea/*
  !.idea/codeStyles/*
```

`codeStyleConfig.xml` should have this option inside:

```
       <option name="USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS" value="true" />
```

so that code style is taken from the project rather than from IDE.

And then go to `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style` and check if `Scheme` is `Project(Stored in Project)` instead of `Default(Stored in IDE)`. If it is, then your team members should just need to pull the changes, check in the `Code Style` section that all the options are same, **restart the IDE** and that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for Editor Configuration.

In your Editor settings (`Preferences > Editor > Code Style`)
choose the **Project** option for the **Scheme** (default is IDE) and export the Configuration file as shown on the screenshot below. This will create `.editorconfig` file in your project root folder so you could share it in repo.

To apply created Config over the custom studio editor style please make sure to **Enable EditorConfig support** in the `Preferences > Editor > Code Style`.

[image]